# Error during compiling application template written with Eliom of Ocsigen Start

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

When I try to compile an application template of Ocsigen Start following [this instruction](https://github.com/ocsigen/ocsigen-start/blob/master/template.distillery/README.md), the error shown below happens at `make test.byte`. Could you tell me how to fix this?

```
LC_ALL=C ocsigen-i18n-generator \
--languages en,fr \
--default-language en \
--primary myapp_i18n.tsv \
< assets/myapp_Demo_i18n.tsv \
> myapp_Demo_i18n.eliom
eliomc -w +A-4-7-9-37-38-39-41-42-44-45-48 -ppx -ppx "ocsigen-i18n-rewriter --prefix 'Myapp_' --suffix '_i18n' Myapp_i18n" -infer -package lwt_ppx -package js_of_ocaml-ppx_deriving_json -package ppx_deriving.std -package pgocaml -package ocsigen-start.server myapp_Demo_i18n.eliom
File "myapp_Demo_i18n.eliom", line 1, characters 24-37:
1 | let%shared languages = [Myapp_i18n.En;Myapp_i18n.Fr]
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Unbound constructor Myapp_i18n.En
make: *** [Makefile.os:213: _server/myapp_Demo_i18n.type_mli] Error 2
rm myapp_Demo_i18n.eliom
```

Comment: Are you sure that there's a module `En` in your `Myapp_i18n`? What I mean is that this problem seems to come from your implementation, not Ocsigen or Eliom, but since we don't have access to your files it may be a bit hard to find where the problem comes from.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! The file is automatically removed if compilation fails. But, yes, I guess no the module `En`. I just thought everything needed is generated automatically and therefore I don't understand why the module is missing.